# How to create /etc/.java/deployment directory

Tags: command-line, 13.10

How to create /etc/.java/deployment directory and to move DeploymentRuleSet.jar file in that directory which sits on my desktop. I need this so I can use my netbanking but since I'm a new Linux user (very new) I dont know to use it. I tried but nothing.

Can anyone write commands for terminal step by step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal, by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Use the following command in the terminal,

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/.java/deployment
sudo cp ~/Desktop/DeploymentRuleSet.jar /etc/.java/deployment
```

This will do the job.